# Doctrine2 many-to-many

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to get one user who are members of more than one group. So, I have the variable groupsId but don't know how to add a "where in" when I have "member of".

```
$userId = 1;
$groupsId = array(1, 2, 3);

$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.id FROM user u WHERE u.id = :userId and :groupsId MEMBER OF u.groups');
$query->setParameter(':userId', $userId);
$query->setParameter(':groupsId', $groupsId);
$ids = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not tested yet

```
SELECT u.id FROM user u JOIN u.groups g WITH g.id IN :groupsId WHERE u.id = :userId AND SIZE(u.groups) > 1
```

**SIZE(u.groups) > 1** check user membership in more than one groups.

Comment: But I have annotation in each entities so I don't need to use "JOIN". For this reason I use "MEMBER OF".
My entities are look like the next example you can find in:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html
look for by "Many-To-Many, Bidirectional"

Comment: With MEMBER OF you can check entry of ONE group IN COLLECTION of group. But you need a groups defined in :groupsId by id,  right?

Comment: yes, I wants to know how many groups are a specific user. For example, user with id 1 have 1, 2 and 3 groupId

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QueryBuilder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) instead, which helps you build queries much faster and easier.

You can do something like:

```
    $expr = $em->getExpressionBuilder();
    $query = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\User')
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u.id', 'count(g.id) as HIDDEN cnt')
        ->innerJoin('u.groups', 'g', 'WITH', $expr->in('g.id', ':groupsIds'))
        ->where('u.id = :userId')
        ->having('cnt > 1')
        ->setParameters(array(
            'userId' => 1,
            'groupsIds' => array(1, 2, 3),
        ))
        ->groupBy('u.id')
        ->getQuery();

    var_dump($query->getResult());
    die;
```

**EDIT:** I have improved the query as I just noticed you wish to have *more than one group*.